# What is the best way to delete array item in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

Could you tell me your way to delete an item from array? Do you think it's good?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That depends:

```
$a1 = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3);
unset($a1['b']);
// array('a' => 1, 'c' => 3)

$a2 = array(1, 2, 3);
unset($a2[1]);
// array(0 => 1, 2 => 3)
// note the missing index 1

// solution 1 for numeric arrays
$a3 = array(1, 2, 3);
array_splice($a3, 1, 1);
// array(0 => 1, 1 => 3)
// index is now continous

// solution 2 for numeric arrays
$a4 = array(1, 2, 3);
unset($a4[1]);
$a4 = array_values($a4);
// array(0 => 1, 1 => 3)
// index is now continous
```

Generally [`unset()`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) is safe for hashtables (string-indexed arrays), but if you have to rely on continous numeric indexes you'll have to use either [`array_splice()`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) or a combination of `unset()` and [`array_values()`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php).

Comment: Why would you use unset combined with array_values rather than array_splice?

Comment: @John: One scenario I can think about is, when you want to remove several items from one array. With the `unset()`-way you can remove the values without having to think about changing keys - if you're done your run the array through `array_values()` to normalize the indexing. That's cleaner and faster than using `array_splice()` several times.

Answer (score 10):

**The common way:**

According to the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

```
unset($arr[5]); // This removes the element from the array
```

**The filtered way:**

There is also the [array_filter()](https://www.php.net/array_filter) function to take care of filtering arrays

```
$numeric_data = array_filter($data, "is_numeric");
```

To get a sequential index you can use

```
$numeric_data = array_values($numeric_data);
```

**References**
[PHP – Delete selected items from an array](http://blog.joshschumacher.com/2007/03/22/php-delete-selected-items-from-an-array/)

Answer (score 6):

It depends. If want to remove an element without causing gaps in the indexes, you need to use array_splice:

```
$a = array('a','b','c', 'd');
array_splice($a, 2, 1);
var_dump($a);
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "a"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "b"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "d"
}
```

Using unset can work, but this results in a non-continuous index. This can sometimes be a problem when you iterate over the array using count($a) - 1 as a measure of the upper bound:

```
$a = array('a','b','c', 'd');
unset($a[2]);
var_dump($a);
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "a"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "b"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "d"
}
```

As you see, count is now 3 but the index of the last element is also 3.

My recommendation is therefore to use array_splice for arrays with numerical indexes, and use unset only for arrays (dictionaries really) with non-numerical indexes.

Comment: alternatively you could call `unset($a[2]); $a = array_values($a);`